# How can i declare list in a Json object?

Tags: c#, .net, json, list, json.net

I have a json object declaration in which i want to use a list of DateTime. How can i declare it? I get a error in the current definition.

```
public class TurtleTrade
{        
    [JsonProperty("Powerbars")]
    public int  Powerbars { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("PowerbarsTime")]
    public List<DateTime>()  PowerbarsTime { get; set; } // Error here
}
```

Comment: remove the parens.

Comment: *I get a error in the current definition* - What is the error you are getting?

Comment: public List<DateTime>  PowerbarsTime { get; set; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated the issues/Error is not because of the `[JsonProperty("PowerbarsTime")]` You can define List under it. The real issues is the declaration syntax of `List<T>`. `List<DateTime>()` is not a valid declaration of a List of DateTime it must be `List<DateTime>` So  `public List<DateTime>()  PowerbarsTime { get; set; }` should be like this :

```
public List<DateTime> PowerbarsTime { get; set; }
```